# Kendo Grid Custom Confirmation Message Box For Destroy Command

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, command, kendo-grid, destroy, confirmation

How can we replace the default Kendo UI Grid Destroy command confirmation box with custom confirmation box/message ?

I am working on ASP.NET MVC4 application.And i want to show custom confirmation instead of default.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot replace it but still you can change its message:

```
editable: {
 mode: "incell",
 confirmation: "Are you sure?" // the confirmation message for destroy command
},
```